# What's the meaning of the class indicator matrix when transforming the class label matrix into it in canonical correlation analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, st.statistics

When using canonical correlation analysis (CCA), we can integrate the dataset and label information via transforming the class label matrix *Y* into the class indicator matrix *T*. Such as: $T = (YY^T)^½Y$ in [this article on LS CCA][1].

While for the numeric dataset and the binary dataset, the binary dataset can be viewed as the class label matrix and transformed into the class indicator matrix. After that, should I use the CCA?

Though without this transformation, [the CCA can be used][2], I'd like to know how to explian this kind of transformation once using it on the binary dataset (not label matrix). Thank you.

Comment: This might be better suited for [stats.se]

Comment: Well, I do, But nobody reply it. Consequently, I posted it here because I believe it's also a machine learning problem.